# What is the name of this flower? The photo was taken in the Okanagan Valley, British Columbia

Tags: species-identification, flowers

This little flower was growing on dry ranchland in Kelowna, it flowered in April:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks a lot like [*Claytonia lanceolata*](http://www.pnwflowers.com/flower/claytonia-lanceolata)

Comment: Yes it is.rundown